# flask how to not to show the error page when using @app.errorhandler(Exception) but continue with application flow

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

i have

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def unhandled(error):
    print(error)
    etype, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb))
    logger.error("Exception %s" % traceback.format_exc())
    logger.error("Exception %s" % traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb))
    logger.info("Exception %s" % traceback.format_exc())
    logger.info("Exception %s" % traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb))
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    return None

@app.route('/')
def index():
    logger.info("A %s- B: %s" % project_dict)   # raise exception 
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
```

the problem is that i don't what this function to break the flow of the calling handler @app.route('/')
just to print to log and continue to

```
a = 1
 b = 2
 c = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of integrating the possible faulty execution into a try-except block?

```
# This code is never executed due to an error that occurs within 
# the try-except block in the route `index`.
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def unhandled(error):
    return make_response('Internal Server Error', 400)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
       # Your code that may throw an error.
       raise Exception('something went wrong') # raise exception
    except Exception as exc: 
       # Handle exception here!
       pass 
    else:
       # This code is executes if no exception occurs.
       pass 
    finally:
       # This code is executed despite an exception.
       pass 
    # ...
```

Comment: the problem of that is i will need to add many try/catch to the server in fact to each 
app.route , and i have many . i want to avoid it ,

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap it in a decorator, but it depends on the situation. I think my answer is the best and most versatile solution to your problem. Boilerplate code shouldn't just reduce the work of the programmer. Maybe you could redirect back to the route after the error_handler has been executed, but it will start again from the beginning and may cause the exception again. It's also a pretty dirty approach. Are you familiar with context managers? I'm afraid your requirements are too general to give a more appropriate answer.

Comment: thanks but your answer is the standard way which i like to avoid

Comment: The last thought that I can give you is to integrate middleware, which realizes a custom exception handling. I think it doesn't keep the flow of your application.  
I also thank you and wish you much success with this and your further projects.